# Why do I have smaller than expected floor joist components?

Tags: floor

I cut out the subfloor in my half bath on 2nd story above garage. I didn't expect to see 2x4s proving the most support, and just one 2x6 joist. Can someone explain to this newbie what's going on? Thanks.[image][image]

Answer (score 4):

Those are modern engineered floor trusses, or truss joists. They often have flat 2x3 or 2x4 top and bottom chords and a web of diagonals and verticals between.

The 2x you see is a stiffener, or "stiffback", which ties the trusses together to spread load and minimize movement and vibration.

It looks a bit like someone cut out some of the stiffener, maybe to get a duct in the space below. The builder may have added additional stiffeners nearby.

Comment: Thanks! Would it be inadvisable to block those truss joists with flat 2x4s? So I can install new subfloor?

Comment: Go ahead and add joint blocking wherever you like. Subfloors usually have tongue-and-groove connections, so it's a good idea.  I'd use construction adhesive or screws or both.